# ConcurrentModificationException - multiythreading

Tags: multithreading, exception, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I have an Update System :

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Main.frame.onUpdate();
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    for (Entity e : Main.frame.getEntityHandler().getEntities()) {
                        e.onUpdate();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

and sometimes it gives an ConcurrentModificationException. Why is this happening? The Exception :

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
at de.crade.ki.logic.update.UpdateHandler$1.run(UpdateHandler.java:15)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Don’t use multiple threads until you have understood multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly, here 
`for (Entity e : Main.frame.getEntityHandler().getEntities()`
 is an iteration on the collection "entities". when you're doing iteration under multi-threading environment, if other threads modifies the "entities" at the same time, the iterator would catch this and throw the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. one easy fix is to add the lock on the iteration process like this `new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Main.frame.onUpdate();
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        synchronized{
                            for (Entity e : Main.frame.getEntityHandler().getEntities()) {
                                e.onUpdate();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();` 
But this would add extra performance penalty. not sure whether you want to do that.